# "Permission denied" using PostgreSQL COPY in Travis-CI

Tags: node.js, postgresql, csv, travis-ci, pg

I'm using **travis-ci.org** to test a Node.js module.
It uses the latest [pg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg) package to access a PostgreSQL database.

The integration tests need to use the Postgres `copy` command (from within a transaction... not psql's `\copy`) to populate a temporary table with some **CSV** data.
**Everything passes locally**... but running on Travis-CI I'm hitting:

```
"COPY some_table(column_a,column_b) FROM 
'/home/travis/build/my_org/my_repo/test/fixtures/some_file.csv' CSV HEADER;"
{ error: could not open file 
"/home/travis/build/my_org/my_repo/test/fixtures/some_file.csv" for reading: 
Permission denied
    at Connection.parseE 
(/home/travis/build/my_org/my_repo/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:567:11)
    at Connection.parseMessage   name: 'error',
...
```

So a file `Permission denied` is the thing. My noob Linux skills tell me the file at that location exists. I've tried `chmod`ing it to 777, but that didn't have any effect.

I'm connecting to Postgres on Travis with the string:

```
postgres://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432
```

And all's well with that.
One thing, I do need PostgreSQL **V9.6**, so my `.travis.yml` file looks like:

```
language: node_js

node_js:
  - "6"

services:
  - postgresql

addons:
  postgresql: "9.6"

sudo: false
dist: trusty
```

...which has worked great in the past, but this is the first time I've ever had to use `copy`.

I guess it's something to do with whatever user Postgres is running as somehow?

**Any help very gratefully received!**

Tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually ran into this issue when I was working on an inherited code base which was using the old Travis infrastructure (based on Ubuntu Precise) and wanted to update it to Trusty.

The Precise-based image had no problem reading a file from the travis home directory - maybe the PostgreSQL server was running as the `travis` user, not as `postgres`, but on Trusty this was not the case and I got this error.

Using `chmod` on the file itself is not enough, the server still can't read from the `travis` home directory. So you could create a file using `mktemp`, copy your file to it, change those permissions to `666` using `chmod`. Now you're able to read it in using PostgreSQLs `COPY FROM`.